# Удалить элементы массива с не парными индексами

Tags: c++

Я сделал массив,заполнил его случайными числами до 100 нашел индексы элементов,но мне нужно удалить те элементы индексы которых являються не парными ,не понимаю как это сделать,ошибка скорее всего здесь.

```
 if (k % 2 != 0) {
        }
            cout << arr[i]--;
        }
    





#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int const  size = 10;
    int arr[size];
        int k=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
     cout << arr[i]<< " ";
        k++;
        cout << k << " " << endl;
    if (k % 2 != 0) {
    }
        cout << arr[i]--;
    }
    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Видите ли, ну вот есть у вас массив. Что означает **удалить из него элемент**? Как вы себе это представляете? При том, что размер **массива** во время выполнения программы вы менять не можете. Как только вы ответите на этот вопрос - все станет проще...

Comment: всмысле что означает удалить элемент,мне задание такое дали,что нужно элемент удалить,я конечно понимаю что массив нужно перезаписывать,но можно ли произвести удаление без перезаписи массива?

Comment: если массив объявлен как `int arr[size];` то его размер изменить нельзя (а значит и просто так удалить элемент). Но если использовать плюсовые массивы - `std::vector<int> arr;` то все легко - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: Я просто не понимаю тогда смысла давать преподавателю задание которое нельзя выполнить через обычный массив,а нужно делать через вектор,если через массив задание сделать не возможно,через вектор понятное дело что все легко.

Comment: Индексы не парные с чем? Или это украинское "чётные" имеется в виду? Каково точное задание?

Comment: Так, разжевываю дальше. У вас имеется не просто массив, а массив и его длина. И удаление - это только когда новая длина меньше старой - скажем, был массив `int a[100];`, с заполнением на 20 элементов. Вот входные данные - массив и 20. На выходе - массив и новая длина. А что должно произойти с элементами? Ну, давайте, не разжевывать же все полностью за вас...

Comment: вектор это и есть плюсовый массив. Поэтому задание вполне можно выполнить.