# Удалить с 5-го по 9-й элементы из массива Х = {xi}, i = 1, ... 11

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int X[11] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };
}
```

Comment: Удалить с 5-го по 9-й элементы из массива Х = {xi}, i = 1, ... 11. Составить алгоритм и написать программный код решения задачи. Начальное количество элементов массива определить константой. Предусмотреть введение массива Х и вывод его после преобразования.

Comment: Искал как можно удалить, но находил только примеры удаления первого и последнего элемента массива. Подскажите как решить пожалуйста.

Comment: А массив обязательно статический?

Comment: Думаю не обязательный .

Comment: Тогда просто создаете новый временный массив размером,  в вашем случае, `n - 5`, где `n` размер массива `X` и копируете нужные элементы в новый временный массив, потом удаляете массив `X` и присваиваете ему указатель на новый. Все

Comment: Почитайте комментарии под вопросами здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1223606/344284 и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1200323/344284, там написано как раз про "удаление" элементов из массива С/С++ и про то, что реальное удаление, по сути, невозможно. Можно сделать только перезапись со сдвигом остальных элементов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите все детали вопроса в самом вопросе (кнопка "править"), а не в комментариях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно под этим подразумевается перемещение элементов + поддержание фактического размера массива отдельно. Примерно

```
int X[11] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };

int X_size = 11;

for(int i = 9; i < X_size; ++i)
    X[i-5] = X[i];

X_size -= 5;

for(int i = 0; i < X_size; ++i) cout << X[i] << " ";
```